# Não mostrar setas do "overflow"

Tags: html, css

Possuo uma `td` com `overflow`.

```
<td><div><?php echo $objProg->getagen(); ?></div></td>
```

Css:

```
td div {

width:100%; 
height: 30px; 
overflow: auto; 

}
```

Com esse CSS acima fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que as setas do lado do texto ficassem ocultas porem o scroll do mouse funcionar mesmo assim para ir para baixo e para cima, existe algo que faça isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa que encontrei (não sei se a melhor, pois nunca precisei fazer isso) seria utilizando uma margem negativa na div. Por exemplo:

```
table tbody tr td {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table tbody tr td div {
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0 -20px 0 0;
}
```

Você coloca `overflow: hidden` na célula pai, e controla o `scroll` na `div` filho, dando a ela uma margem negativa, para que se estenda além da célula. O `overflow: hidden` na célula é importante para não deixar que a seta apareça 'fora' do `td`.

Veja funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/v1ry5rko/

Comment: +1 . A idéia é boa, mas talvez seja o caso de aumentar a margem e usar um padding na direita, para caso a pessoa esteja usando uma configuração de DPI diferente, e a barra fique ampliada.

Comment: Tens como fazer com que a rolagem do scroll seja mais "lenta" ?

Comment: Se você pretende usar somente `css` e `html` a resposta é não. Mas com javascript (`jQuery` por exemplo) você consegue, existe diversos plugins para isso. Procure por Smooth scroll (scroll suave) que você encontra =D

Answer (score 2):

Olhe meu exemplo, não sei se entendi certo mas foi no que cheguei.

Somente quando você colocar o mouse na div as barras de rolagem aparecem.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/z892h4oc/

Comment: Não é isso que ele deseja. O objetivo seria nunca exibir a barra de rolagem sem remover a função de scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar isso aqui:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;
}
```

Aplica isso ao td da sua div. Boa sorte.

Comment: Tentei, não rolou.

Comment: Ainda que funcionasse, isso só resolveria para WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

```
td {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

td div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 17px; /* Aumente e diminua esse valor para compatibilidade cross-browser */
}
```

Comment: Não deu, eu quero esconder essas setas do lado não quero que nem uma apareça só quero que role com o scroll quando por o mouse encima.